# Why TabControl.SelectedContent != (TabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem).Content?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

The following sample shouldn't beep (in my opinion) but it does. Why? Does that mean the `SelectedContent` property is useless? Is it a bug in WPF?

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <Grid/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <Grid/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

```
void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = sender as TabControl;
    if (t.SelectedContent != (t.SelectedItem as TabItem).Content) Console.Beep();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing and found that the SelectedContent property is set *after* the SelectionChanged Event has been consumed, while the SelectedItem is set *before* the event is raised.!

Change one of the Grids to a Stackpanel and set a breakpoint on your if clause...

Answer (score 1):

It indeed looks like a bug in WPF. See, in this code:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TabControl.cs,342
it first calls `base.OnSelectionChanged` (which raises the `SelectionChanged` event), then attempts to set the focus to the selected `TabItem` (which incidentally also fails since the new content is not displayed yet), and only then calls `UpdateSelectedContent`, which actually sets the `SelectedContent` to the new value (content of the new tab).

So yes, the `SelectionChanged` event is kind of useless. A good workaround is to subscribe to when the `SelectedContent` dependency property value is changed:

```
var dp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TabControl.SelectedContentProperty, typeof(TabControl));
dp.AddValueChanged(tabControl, OnTabControlSelectedContentChanged);
```

If you set a breakpoint in `OnTabControlSelectedContentChanged` you'll notice that it is raised after `SelectionChanged`, and by that time the content should be updated. Don't forget also to set the focus to the new content manually (since WPF's attempt to set focus fails). To set the focus, might need to do `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` as usual.