# TabControl always contains "old" value in SelectedContent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TabControl:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" SelectionChanged="MainTabControl_OnSelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabItem Header="First Tab">Content for the first tab</TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Second Tab">Content for the second tab</TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Third Tab">Content for the third tab</TabItem>
```

with this Eventhandler:

```
private void MainTabControl_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainTabControl.SelectedContent != null)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine(MainTabControl.SelectedContent);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("null");
    }
}
```

Now the problem:

When I switch Tabs, always the "old" Content is written.
And I already played with **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem** set to true or false.

Why?

Comment: The problem also exists, when I use Bindings as ItemSource.

Comment: Use the [`SelectedItem` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.

Comment: Sheridan pushed me in the right direction. Thank you! (And yes, this whole question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2551792/376086)